# IntelliSense duplicating part of table/field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 (10.50.4000). When I start typing the IntelliSense pops up and offers tables/columns. When I press tab to select and start typing further the IntelliSense adds characters. It is difficult to explain so hopefully the following screens will help:

I start typing:

[image]

I press TAB to select the table:

[image]

I press enter to go to next line to add my WHERE clause:

[image]

Has anyone seen anything like this before and if so can you please help.

Thanks

Comment: That's not the standard SSMS IntelliSense. Look like Red Gate SQL add in to me.

Comment: I agree with @ZoffDino. Check these screenshots:
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/sql-server-intellisense-vs.-red-gate-sql-prompt/

Comment: You are correct Zoff and Andrew. The link helped enormously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the responses this was to do with RedGate SQL Prompt. I turned it off and everything works fine now. I am unsure why it only affects certain versions of SQL though.

Thanks all